# Minimum valence of a vertex in a simple triangular mesh with no boundaries

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, computer-science

Suppose M is a simple (manifold, orientable and connected) triangular mesh with no boundaries (in other words, a mesh homeomorphic to a sphere).

I have the conjecture that the following statement is true:

> The valence (the number of connecting edges) of
>   each vertex is greater or equal than 3.

My current definition of manifoldness is that each edge is incident to only one or two faces and the faces incident to a vertex form a closed or an open fan.

Valence is a natural number by definition, so:

- Valence = 0 breaks connectivity
- Valence = 1 breaks manifoldness because the only edge associated to the vertex would not be able to be incident to any face.

However I am having problems proving that Valence = 2 should break the manifoldness condition.

Can someone help me to better understand those conditions so I can prove if the statement is either false or true?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. It took me the entire day to realize. It probably deserves a more formal proof, but at least it is an argument:

If a vertex has valence 2, the 2 neighboring vertices must have 2 edges connecting the same 2 vertices. This would make the edges in the star of v boundaries, as they would be homeomorphic to the closed upper half-plane.

So, in this case, it is guaranteed that each vertex in a 2-manifold mesh with no boundaries has valence greater or equal to 3.

[image: Diagram of valence = 2 case]

Comment: What is the "manifold condition"? Surely if you glue triangles together like in your diagram, the result will be a perfectly good _topological manifold_.

Comment: The "manifold condition" I am referring is that each vertex has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an open disk. But you are right! My writing was poor and perhaps even wrong. The diagram indeed is a good topological manifold, but it has a boundary (which could not exist according to hypothesis).

Comment: I'm assuming that there are other triangles than the ones in the diagram. But even so, if you take _two_ triangles and glue them together at the edges, you get a perfectly good topological manifold, homeomorphic to the sphere. I don't get why you think the red edges in your diagram would be a boundary -- there's clearly surface to both sides of each of them.

Comment: If you glue two (flat) triangles at the edges, wouldn't you have a set that is itself a (flat) triangle, hence being homeomorphic to a disk, not a sphere?

Comment: x @Albu: Um, no. Only of you glue the _interiors_ of the triangles together rather than just the _edges_.